# Converting data types in SQL Server using CAST

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I'm new to SQL Server and I would like to know how to convert data types in SQL Server. As far as I know SQL Server doesn't support format mask (ex.'YYYY-MM-DD' or '999'). It's basically about all data types, not only `DATE` data type as below.

Let's say that I want to convert '20240512' to 2024-12-05, NOT default one: 2024-05-12.

In Oracle I can use TO_DATE and CAST - both functions support mask.

```
SELECT 
    TO_DATE('20240512')      AS wrong1,
    CAST('20240512' AS DATE) AS wrong2,
    TO_DATE('20240512', 'YYYYDDMM') AS correct1,
    CAST('20240512' AS DATE, 'YYYYDDMM') AS correct2;
```

In Postgres I can use `TO_DATE`. CAST doesn't support format mask.

And what about SQL Server, when `TO_DATE` doesn't exists and `CAST` doesn't support format mask?

Comment: in TSQL you can use `CAST` which is ANSI-SQL standard, or the more flexible `CONVERT` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16.
`CONVERT` accepts a style parameter when converting to a string: `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)`. It is worth pointing out that formatting a date does make it a string, as a `DATE` does not have a format.

Comment: `Let's say that I want to convert` your expectations are *very* unusual and the cause of several serious errors. `YYYYMMDD` is a very specific format used to *avoid* localization issues. Same with the ISO8601 form, `YYYY-MM-DD`. If you use `YYYYDDMM` strings, you're doing something or rather *several* things wrong. First of all, you're passing strings instead of `date` values around. Second, and probably worse, you're using a completely unexpected format that subverts a well known standard. That's just *begging* for failures

Comment: @PatrickHurst Looks like OP needs `yyyyddmm` which is not an available style. So maybe use `FORMAT`.

Comment: `Sql Server doesn't support format mask` it does, using the `CONVERT`, `PARSE`, or `FORMAT` functions. The conversion you ask for though is essentially ..... evil. It will confuse *every single developer* and even yourself. By next month if not next Monday you won't remember you used a custom format instead of the standard one you see everywhere. You *will* convert `20240104` to April 1.

Comment: @PatrickHurst  And what about data migration? I can imagine situation when I need to convert string like YYYYDDMM to a DATE.  I could provide much more examples when default conversion result is an error on unexpected result, ex.
SELECT --TO_DATE('2024-05//12', 'YYYY-DD//MM')   AS it_works
    CAST('2024-05//12' AS DATE)          AS it_wont
    ;

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos could you provide example how to use the 3 functions to get 2022-12-05 from '20240512?

Comment: Could you explain on what's the purpose of getting year 2022 from 20240512

Comment: @drk you can't convert `12345678` to a date either. In the case you specify you're looking for the database to perform your ETL sanitation, which isn't really it's job. If you really want to convert 'YYYYDDMM' to a `DATE` you should be parsing the input to be able to provide it in a standard order, but it is possible: `SELECT '20233011', TRY_CAST('20230311' AS DATE), CAST(LEFT('20230311',4)+RIGHT('20230311',2)+SUBSTRING('20230311',5,2) AS DATE)`

Comment: for date formatting, check out: FORMAT function. Ie, `SELECT FORMAT(cast('20240512' as date), 'yyyy-dd-MM')`

Comment: For string to date formatting, i'd probably write a custom function.

Comment: Don't use `'YYYYDDMM'`. Use ISO8601 instead- `yyyy-MM-dd`  for date or `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` for datetime.

Comment: @drk can you explain *one* valid reason why this backwards, unsortable format is used? You're asking for help to shoot yourself in the foot. I want to know why before I answer. Chances are you don't have to.

Comment: @siggemannen when someone asks for help to shoot themselves in the foot, you aren't helping them by showing how to turn off the safety

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I haven't read the whole discussion, but there are always legitimate reasons to use "local dateformats", for example in reports to clients

Comment: @siggemannen the question asks how to parse YYYYDDMM to a date. That means either the client sends dates as strings (a bug) or stores dates as strings (also a bug). In both cases one can only assume what the format was and hope the client or the ETL job that loaded the data didn't make a mistake. The way to avoid this is to store dates using a date type and parse input *before* it's sent to the database.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos hmm, yeah, maybe you're right. I was reading it as he wanted to format date to a string. My bad

Comment: You store a date in a bad and unintuitive format, you get to use bad and unintuitive solutions. https://dbfiddle.uk/XV5dJ1_u

Comment: @drk said, "I can imagine situation when I need to convert string like YYYYDDMM to a DATE."   So, you're just asking this question hypothetically? You don't currently have a real business requirement to do this?

Comment: @HardCode Exactly. I haven't met the string in any project, but I was only curious how to solve such hypothetical situation.

Comment: @drk okay, so since it's hypothetical, I hope you realize the true answer is "don't do it"?

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the comment's as an answer:

`YYYYMMDD` is a very specific format used to avoid localization issues. Same with the ISO8601 form, `YYYY-MM-DD`. - [panagiotis-kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos)

in TSQL you can use `CAST` which is ANSI-SQL standard, or the more flexible `CONVERT` - [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). CONVERT accepts a style parameter when converting to a string: `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)`. It is worth pointing out that formatting a date does make it a string, as a `DATE` does not have a format. – [Patrick Hurst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18522514/patrick-hurst)

Looks like OP needs `yyyyddmm` which is not an available style. So maybe use `FORMAT`. – [Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface)

you can't convert `12345678` to a date either. In the case you specify you're looking for the database to perform your ETL sanitation, which isn't really it's job. If you really want to convert 'YYYYDDMM' to a `DATE` you should be parsing the input to be able to provide it in a standard order, but it is possible:
`SELECT '20233011', TRY_CAST('20230311' AS DATE), CAST(LEFT('20230311',4)+RIGHT('20230311',2)+SUBSTRING('20230311',5,2) AS DATE)`  – [Patrick Hurst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18522514/patrick-hurst)

Sql Server doesn't support format mask it does, using the `CONVERT`, `PARSE`, or `FORMAT` functions. The conversion you ask for though is essentially ..... evil. It will confuse every single developer and even yourself. By next month if not next Monday you won't remember you used a custom format instead of the standard one you see everywhere. You will convert 20240104 to April 1. –
[panagiotis-kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos)